# Unable to see arrow direction in `graphjs` from `igraph` object

Tags: r, graph, three.js, igraph, networkx

I am running the following code for an `igraph` object, I could see arrows when I use just `plot`, but I am unable to see arrows when I use `threejs` library

```
# Make a correlation matrix:
mat=cor(t(mtcars[,c(1,3:6)]))
# Keep only high correlations
mat[mat<0.995]=0 
# Make an Igraph object from this matrix:
net=graph_from_adjacency_matrix( mat, weighted=T, mode="directed", diag=F)
graphjs(net)
```